# Bypassing Linux cluster gateway - going directly to node from your desktop

Tags: linux, unix, networking, ssh, cluster-computing

From my desktop I usually executing this command to go to linux cluster:

I have this in my `.bash_profile`

```
alias gothere="ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_macmini_mine pdubois@thelinux.cluster.co.jp"
```

Then call it with this to go to the cluster:

```
dhcp190-206:~ pdubois-macmini$ gothere
Last login: Tue Mar 25 15:41:03 2014 from dhcp190-206.mycompany-u.ac.jp
[pdubois@thelinuxcluster ~]$
```

Then once I reach the gateway of that cluster I do this again to go to the node:

```
alias blogin="bsub -Is -q intj bash -l"
```

Call it this way to go to the node:

```
[pdubois@thelinuxcluster ~]$ blogin 
Job <221825> is submitted to queue <intj>.
<<Waiting for dispatch ...>>
<<Starting on clusternode61>>
[pdubois@clusternode61 ~]$
```

My question is, is there a way I can simplify the above two steps into one step?
So that I can go directly to the cluster node from my desktop.

Comment: I'm not sure but `ssh -t -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_macmini_mine pdubois@thelinux.cluster.co.jp bsub -Is -q intj bash -l` may work.

Comment: Not it doesn't work. It gave me `bash: bsub: command not found`.

Comment: maybe your PATH or alias is not set, to read ~/.bashrc when ssh -t, read http://superuser.com/questions/207200/how-can-i-set-environment-variables-for-a-remote-rsync-process/207262 or http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23633/source-profile-and-bashrc-on-ssh-login-without-tty

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not related to programming.

Answer (score 1):

The ssh is a login to a user node (gateway as you called it) on the cluster, the `bsub` with `-I` is an interactive job submission request which puts you on the cluster by running an interactive job on a compute node.

So no, you can't combine these two. The interactive job is started from the user node.

Perhaps more importantly, once you login to the "gateway", you are effectively "on" the cluster already for programming and debugging purposes. Access to the nodes should be reserved for job submission and interactive debugging jobs. Once you run the `bsub` command, your account is being charged for time on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

```
alias gothere="ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_macmini_mine pdubois@thelinux.cluster.co.jp \"bsub -Is -q intj bash -l\""
```

Gotta escape the double quotes!